# Minecraft Launcher: Cannot get main method need assistance

Tags: java, minecraft

I am trying to create a simple launcher for Minecraft 1.7.10. However, when I try to get the main method from `net.minecraft.client.main.Main` I get the error:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: joptsimple/OptionSpec.

I've tried studying code from other launchers to see how they get around this issue, but I cant see any difference.

```java
public Method getMainMethod() throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, 
                                    ClassNotFoundException, IOException, 
                                    InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException  
{            
    return new URLClassLoader(new URL[] {new URL("file:///" + 
                                    MinecraftUtil.getBinFolder() + "/minecraft.jar")}, 
                                    URLClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getParent())
                                    .loadClass("net.minecraft.client.main.Main")
                                    .getMethod("main", String[].class);
}
```

This is supposed to get the main method from minecraft.jar and allow me to invoke it, but if I even try to load the class it spits the joptsimple/optionspec error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include all libraries that Minecraft need in this class loader too, if you will look at typical Minecraft installation you will notice that there is `\libraries` folder with a lot of sub directories and other .jar at the end of them, and you need to load all needed ones.

Minecraft use profiles to keep track of needed libraries, there should be `versions` folder and each version contains .jar of that version and .json file with all the libraries you need to load:

```
"libraries": [
    {
        "name": "com.mojang:patchy:1.1",
        "downloads": {
            "artifact": {
                "size": 15817,
                "sha1": "aef610b34a1be37fa851825f12372b78424d8903",
                "path": "com/mojang/patchy/1.1/patchy-1.1.jar", 
                "url": "https://libraries.minecraft.net/com/mojang/patchy/1.1/patchy-1.1.jar"
            }
        }
    },
```

And you can find size of .jar file, sha1 checksum, path in that libraries directory, and link to download it if it is missing. So you can implement launcher that will download libraries that are missing.

You could use these existing profiles or just make your own system to keep track of libraries you need to include in that class loader.
Note that profiles also include all the parameters you need to pass to Minecraft main method to run the game - you need these too.